# libusb - Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, usb, libusb, libusb-1.0

I've got a very basic, bare minimum libusb example going, which compiles, but the output produced by the following application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Looking for USB devices...");

    libusb_device **devices;
    libusb_context *context = NULL;

    ssize_t device_count = 0;

    device_count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &devices);
    if(device_count < 0) {
        puts("Unable to retrieve USB device list!");
    }

    printf("%lu devices found\n", device_count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

is as follows:

```
Looking for USB devices... 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The failure occurs on line 13:

`device_count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &devices);`

I'm running the above on Mac OS X 10.9, and have libusb version 1.0.9 installed via Homebrew.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: You're supposed to initialize that context.

Comment: May be `context` requires to be pointing to some memory instead of being `NULL`. Check the code/documentation of function `libusb_get_device_list`

Comment: Following an example on http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/ show's that = NULL is adequate initialisation for context.

Comment: But will definitely look into it...

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk: Yes, but the example also shows that `libusb_init()` is called on context first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code misses to initialise  `context`.

Call [`libusb_init()`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__lib.html#ga9517c37281bba0b51cc62eba728be48b) prior to any operation on libusb.

Add a line like this before issueing any other call into libusb:

```
 int result = libusb_init(&context); 
 if (0 > result)
 {
   fprintf(stderr, "libusb_init() failed with %d.\n", result);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```